# How to solve android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException in SQLite [multiple questions]?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

[image]

I have the above shown table in my database and the following `query` in my `populate list`

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select id, title, date, week, note, cost, time, catid from entry order by date", null);
```

1. The problem that arises when accessing the `catid` is it throws this `runtime exception`

   ```
   android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 4
   ```

on this line

```
Int id = cursor.getInt(7);
```

> **SOLVED QUESTION --1** 
>   Implented the samething that i have implemented for question 3 but here i am taking `id` as the source for reference

2. Everytime i save the user inputs the app crahses but when it reopens it shows the last taken inputs. It doesn't populate them on runtime
   The error that it shows is (for codes please refer to this question)

   java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=null}

   > **SOLVED QUESTION --2**
   >   Instead of starting the second activity from the mainactivity i'm starting the activity from the intent itself, which solves my problem
3. How do i add particular fields for example in the above table i have a column named `cost` so i want to display the sum of costs of a day how do i do that?

   > **SOLVED QUESTION--3**
   >   I have made a different query method who i am sending the day and based on that it's filtering the ans

**Update 1**

> I have inserted the `id= cursor.getInt(7)` within the do while loop where while is checking `cursor.moveToNext` and i am getting the result with an issue where the last item overlaps all the entries with the same int

Comment: Let me know what number of column returning from `cursor.getColumnCount()` ?

Comment: sir, the columncount is returning `8`

Comment: and `cursor.getCount()` ?

Comment: try `Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from entry", null);` query then check still getting 0 from `cursor.getCount()`

Comment: i am still getting `0`

Comment: means no data available in `entry` table

Comment: But i have data in the entry table

Comment: I mean how u have check data is available in `entry` table?

Comment: i have exported the `database.db` file using the device monitor and opened the file

Comment: Check with `if(cursor.getCount() >0)` then move your cursor.

Comment: Can you please  post your complete query method.

Answer (score 1):

The first question you ask is vague but I can answer the second question which ask basically...how do you sum cost for the day?

```
public double costfortheday(String time1,String time2) {
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor mCursor = database.rawQuery(
            "SELECT SUM (cost) FROM entry order" WHERE time BETWEEN'"
            + time1 + "' AND '" + time2 + "'" , null);

    if (mCursor.moveToFirst()) {
        return mCursor.getDouble(0);
    }
    database.close();
    return mCursor.getDouble(0);

}
```